# How to get value column where column in codeigniter 3

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

I have a table like:

```
sysopt|sysval
......................     
site_url|http://domain.com/
site_title|My Website
......................
```

in mysql i use:

```
$query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM sysconfig");
while ($result = $db->fetch_array($query)) {
    $settings[$result['sysopt']] = $result['sysval'];
}
```

But in CI:

```
class Sysinfo
{
    var $info = array();

public function __construct() 
{
    $CI =& get_instance();
    $settings = $CI->db->select("*")
    ->get("sysconfig");
    foreach($settings as $setting) {
        $this->info[$setting['sysopt']] = $setting['sysval'];
    }
}
```

In view i call:

```
<?php echo $this->Sysinfo->info->site_url; ?>
```

Show error.

```
Message: Undefined property: CI_Loader::$Sysinfo
```

Thankyou any solution fix.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why just not extend the `CI_Model`? For me, in framework..just extend the class so you would be easier

In your model:

```
class Sysinfo extends CI_Model
{
    var $info = array();

    public function __construct() 
    {
        //$CI =& get_instance();
        $settings = $this->db->select("*")
        ->get("sysconfig")->result_array(); //Return result as array
        foreach($settings as $setting) {
            $this->info[$setting['sysopt']] = $setting['sysval'];
        }
    }

    function get_sysinfo_data()
    {
         return $this->info;
    }
}
```

In your Controller

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->load->model('Sysinfo');
}
function index()
{
    $data['arr_result'] = $this->Sysinfo->get_sysinfo_data();
    $this->load->view('your_view',$data);
}
```

In view:

```
foreach($arr_result as $row_array):
     var_dump($row_array); // To view your result
endforeach;
```

---

If you want `Sysinfo` as library..then do like this:

Your library should be name as `Sysinfo.php`:

```
class Sysinfo
{
    var $info = array();

    public function __construct() 
    {
        $CI =& get_instance();
        $settings = $CI->db->select("*")
        ->get("sysconfig")->result_array(); //Return result as array
        foreach($settings as $setting) {
            $this->info[$setting['sysopt']] = $setting['sysval'];
        }
    }

    function get_sysinfo_data()
    {
         return $this->info;
    }
}
```

In your Controller:

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->load->library('Sysinfo');
}
function index()
{
    $data['arr_result'] = $this->Sysinfo->get_sysinfo_data();
    $this->load->view('your_view',$data);
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: It's not controller where the DB operations are performed.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I fixed my mistake. See my codes @FaisalAshfaq

Comment: See my updated answer if you want Sysinfo as library.

Answer (score 0):

The error is appearing because you haven't extended your class with CI_Model base class.

Try defining your class as:

```
class Sysinfo extends CI_Model{ //your code }
```

will get rid of this error message.

Comment: this is library can't use extends CI_Model.

Comment: It's class before it's a library. No?

Comment: I want access global . This class is library